# How to ingest CSV data into kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I need to ingest the csv data into kusto using kusto query for geographical map visualization. but I couldn't find any query to ingest csv data. please help me on this.

Thank you

Comment: The request is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [the One-Click ingestion wizard](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/oneclick) or [ingest-from-storage commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-storage) (requires data to be in Azure Blob or ADLSv2 file.

Comment: thank you so much... is there is any way to ingest through kusto query

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query

Answer (score 0):

You can ingest using query as well as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-storage

You will need to place your files in Azure Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake Store Gen 2.

However, one click ingestion wizard method is advisable as that will ingest data via Data Management component that offers better queuing and ingestion orchestration instead of ingesting directly into database/table using the command shared above.